# SoftLayer API How to get id of load balancer

Tags: rest, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Please tell me  How to get id of load balancer by softlayer API.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following REST request with Account::getAdcLoadBalancer method in order to retrieve the id`s you require.

https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getAdcLoadBalancers

If you require to get more information about specific load balancer you may use SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualIpAddress::getObject specifying the id of the Load Balancer obtained with previous method.

For more information please see below:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Object-Masks